# sql sort by int, except for one int value which has a different order

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I want to sort a list of record from the database. The records retrieved is sorted based on a column with int values. The possible int values are 1,2,3,4,5. The sorting order required is 1,3,2,4,5

so i cannot use `Order by table.a asc`. What should be my query to retrieve the desired order? for example my table has the following record

```
---------------------
name     | to_order |
--------------------
  n1     |  1
--------------------
  n2     |  2
--------------------
  n3     |  3
--------------------
```

The result of my query should be (n1,1),(n3,3),(n2,2).

NOTE: I am using mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add case statements to your order by clause

```
    SELECT name, to_order
FROM Table1
ORDER BY
    (
     CASE
       WHEN to_order = 1 THEN 0
       WHEN to_order = 3 THEN 1
       ELSE 2
     END
    ),
    to_order
```

Add case for 3 so it would be prioritize againts other numbers. I included 1 as case since 1 should still be prioritize before 3

Comment: ,+1 your query works fine too. i updated my answer with similar thing.

Comment: @RADAR yup that will fix it. Removed my down vote on your answer as well :)

Comment: Hi could you explain the case routine, particularly the 0 and 1 after the THEN?

Comment: 0,1,2 are additional sorting column value. Meaning if to order is 1 lets give it maximum sorting advantage by giving it a 0 value and if 3 lets give it 1 and for any other number lets give it 2. for all the 2 numbers it will be sorted by the usual 'to_order' column.

Answer (score 2):

I would write this as:

```
order by (case when to_order = 2 then 3
               when to_order = 3 then 2
               else to_order
          end)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the tightly constrained data you show, a `case` statement is by far the most efficient solution. If, however, you have significantly more than 5 values, or if you might extend to more than 5 values in the future, or if you may have to change the ordering at some time then you might want to decouple the entire process by moving the ordering criteria to a separate table.

```
OldOrder    NewOrder
========    ========
   1           1
   2           3
   3           2
   4           4
   5           5
```

So your query would join on the first field and sort by the second.

```
select ...
from   ...
inner join SortTable st
        on st.OldOrder = to_order
where ...
order by st.NewOrder, ...;
```

Then to add new values or change the sorting order, you just make changes to the table instead of rewriting all your code.